# Hibernate lio con las relaciones

Tags: java, hibernate

Vuelvo a recurrir a ustedes antes de que me acabe volviendo loca de cambiar tanto el código. Tengo que crear desde java con hibernate las tablas de una base datos, concretamente una con esta forma:

```
Tutor:                   Alumno:                          Clase:

id (Int)                 id (Int)                         id (Int) 
nombre (Varchar(50))     nombre (Varchar(50))             curso (Varchar(50))
                         profesor (Int)->id del Tutor     profesor (Int)->id del Tutor 
                                                          estudiante (Int)->id del Alumno
```

El problema lo tengo al definir las relaciones, tengo estas clases pero algo está mal y no encuentro ni dónde ni por qué:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name ="tutor")
public class Tutor {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name ="nombre", nullable =  false)
    private String nombre;

     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "alumno")
     private Set<Alumnos> alumnos;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "asignado")
    private Set<Clase> clases;

    public Tutor (String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.alumnos = new HashSet<Alumno>();
        this.clases = new HashSet<Clases>();
    }
```

```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "alumno")
public class Alumno {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "nombre", nullable = false)
    private String nombre;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "profesor")
    private Tutor tutores;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "alumno")
    private Set<Clase> clases;

    public Alumno(String nombre, Tutor tutores) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.tutores = tutores;
        this.clases = new HashSet<Clase>();
    }
```

```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "clase")
public class Clase {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
     private int id;

    @Column(name = "curso", nullable =  false)
    private String curso;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "estudiante")
    private Alumno alumno;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "clase", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Tutor tutores;


    public Clase (String curso, Alumno alumno, Tutor tutores) {
        this.curso = curso;
        this.alumno = alumno;
        this.tutores = tutores;
    }
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/escuela</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB103Dialect</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <mapping class="colegio.ejemplo.Tutor"/>
        <mapping class="colegio.ejemplo.Alumno"/>
        <mapping class="colegio.ejemplo.Clase"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Creo que me he hecho un lio con los atributos, nombres de las clases y el tipo de relación, podríais ayudarme ante de acumular más errores.

*Aclaración de tablas:*

*El profesor puede tener a más de un alumno (lógico) y también pertenecer a más de una clase*

*El alumno solo tiene un profesor pero puede ir a más de una clase (supongo que tendrá o todas con el mismo o no tendrá en otras... Son cosas de enunciado)*

Otra cosa la forma de conectar que tengo es esta:

```
  public Controlador () {

        StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .configure()
                .build();

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new MetadataSources(registry)
                .buildMetadata()
                .buildSessionFactory();

        this.session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    }
```

Podría ser algo de aquí por lo que no funcione?

Ayer no me salia nada al ejecutar pero hoy me muestra estos errores (no he cambiado nada, no sé porque hoy sí salen):

```
ene. 06, 2021 12:46:45 P. M. org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.9.Final}
ene. 06, 2021 12:46:57 P. M. org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
ene. 06, 2021 12:47:04 P. M. org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.boot.ejemplo.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.boot.ejemplo.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.buildMetadata(MetadataSources.java:185)
    at colegio.Controlador.<init>(Controlador.java:36)
    at colegio.View.showLoginMenu(View.java:38)
    at colegio.View.show(View.java:25)
    at Main.main(Main.java:13)
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.loadDriverIfPossible(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(AggregatedClassLoader.java:210)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at org.hibernate.
```

`Controlador.java:36` es la linea `.buildMetadata()`

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>bases-de-datos</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-colegio</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

**Gracias!**

Comment: Según tu modelo, una clase solo tendrá un tutor y un alumno

Comment: Tutor también? Pero si estoy usando @ManyToMany y creo una tabla auxiliar (asignado) o por lo menos eso creía

Comment: Cual es el error, no funciona el código o tienes alguna excepción en consola.

Comment: No funciona, no creo tablas ni nada similar

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en  Unable to load class [org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver], Busca en la configuracion de conexion de tu base de datos y cambia la clase. Generalmente usan la de mysql(spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver) pero creo que hay una especializada para mariaDB.

Este es mi POM. Solo las dependencias. Yo porque actualmente empleo spring framework. Lo mejor que te sugiero es que uses un ejemplo muy sencillo, solo para leer una tabla y asegures la conexion. Revisa etapa a etapa. Primero la conexion

> 

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Gracias!! Es la primera vez que trabajo con hibernate y no sé donde buscar eso, en el hibernate.cgf.xml? La parte de "dialect"? Buscaré más sobre lo que dijiste

Comment: Lo he cambiado por ```>org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB103Dialect``` pero nada